# Best way to handle SSL client to server to client (relay?)

Tags: ssl, p2p, server

I'm trying to encrypt messages going from client1 to client2, but it cannot be done via peer to peer; because of dynamic IP issues.

I have decided to use a central server, but I'm not sure if the server should just relay the SSL handshake, and any subsequent encrypted message after that (from client1 to client2). The other option I was thinking, was to have the server provide the IP of client2 to client1, and have client1 initiate a direct connection, and do the SSL handshake directly.

Or maybe there is a better way of doing this?

Here are the 2 flows I drew up:

[image]

OR

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a direct connection between the two clients, using the server to faciliate IP discovery, is the best option when possible. Client1 can try to connect to Client2, and if that fails then the clients can switch roles and have Client2 try to connect to Client1.

In case it is not possible to make a direct connection in either direction (such as both clients are behind routers/firewalls that are blocking the connections, and commonly used NAT hole punching techniques fail to open them up), then the server can act as a relay, similar to how a webbrowser can still connect to an HTTPS server when configured to use a proxy server. As long as the server is relying the SSL messages as-is, and the clients are not validating the source IP address of the TCP packets, then it will work.

However, if the clients ARE validating source addresses, then each client will have to establish a separate SSL session between itself and the server, where Client1 sends encrypted data to the server, which decrypts the data and re-encrypts it when sending to Client2, and vice versa.